# Un-able to run windows application on x64-bit PC

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012

I've developed a Windows application with VS 2012 which requires login authentication with MySQL database.

I built it with AnyCPU so I can run on any architecture, so far it runs fine and login is successful when running on x86-bit PC but when I run on x64-bit PC when I try to login, screen turns white for a while and pops up a message saying:

> Could not resolve solution. Contact Microsoft for more information.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dll for connecting to mysql will be an 32 bit und you have to use an 64 bit for 64 bit system...
Compile it as x86 and it will run on both.

Comment: yes you are right my msql.data is 32-bit, so that means i need to reference project with a 64bit mysql.data and compile

Comment: where do i get x64 bit version

Comment: Download from mysql.com

Comment: msql.com gives me 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1) Switch project target to x86, not AnyCPU;
2) Use ODBC to connect MySQL. It has to work with AnyCPU.

Comment: cannot reference project with odbc dll

Comment: option 1 still gave me same problem, my .net connector is 6.9.5